# ¿Como actualizar el estado del comentario padre en el estado del comentario hijo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un modelo de comentarios que puede tener comentarios a los comentarios (comentarios hijos),  quiero que en el modelo, al actualizar el estado del comentario padre, se actualice el nuevo estado del comentario padre a los estados de los comentarios hijos, logre hacerlo desde el controlador, pero es un UPDATE adicional, creo que existe una forma de hacerlo por el modelo y que sea una sola vez la actualización.

**En el controlador tengo:**

```
class ComentariosController < ApplicationController

# ... fragmentos de codigo no relevante

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comentario.update(comentario_params)
        @comentario.comentario_hijos.update_all(estado: @comentario.estado)
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

# ... fragmentos de codigo no relevante

    def comentario_params
      params.require(:comentario).permit(:texto, :estado, :comentario_padre_id)
    end
end
```

**En el modelo tengo:**

```
class Comentario < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :comentario_hijos, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :comentario_padre_id, class_name: :Comentario
  belongs_to :comentario_padre, optional: true, class_name: :Comentario

  validates :estado,
    inclusion: { in: ['A', 'N']
  }

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrígeme si estoy equivocado, pero en `@comentario.update(comentario_params)` estás actualizando el estado del comentario padre **junto con otros atributos**, mientras que en `@comentario.comentario_hijos.update_all(estado: @comentario.estado)` estás actualizando **únicamente el campo `estado`**, ¿cierto?.
No existe forma (que yo sepa y que valga la pena de hacer el esfuerzo de construir esa única query vs hacer 2 `UPDATE` que al fin y al cabo no es nada para tu motor de BD) de hacer un único `UPDATE` donde actualices **múltiples** campos de comentarios, incluido el de `estado`, pero para **ciertos** comentarios (en tu caso, donde el `comentario_padre_id` sea igual al `id`)  solo cambiar el campo de `estado`.
Por otro lado, lo que **si** puedes hacer, si es que solo quieres actualizar el campo de estado, tanto para padre como hijo, es en tu modelo hacer algo como:

```
  VALID_ESTADOS = %w[A N].freeze

  validates :estado, inclusion: { in: VALID_ESTADOS }

  def update_estado(estado)
    return unless VALID_ESTADOS.include?(estado)

    Comentario.where(id: id).or.where(comentario_padre_id: id)
              .update_all(estado: estado)
  end
```

y en tu controlador tener un action exclusivo para cambiar el estado de un comentario y todos sus hijos:

```
class ComentariosController < ApplicationController
  def set_estado
    @comentario.update_estado(params[:estado])
  end
end
```

Y vale la pena repetirlo, este action solo se enfocaría en cambiar el campo de `estado`, no otros campos, pero haría lo que requieres que es cambiar todos los estados en un mismo `UPDATE`.

Comment: Exacto, solo quiero un metodo para actualizar todos los estados, excelente. gracias.